# pass value back from a view controller to another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uistoryboardsegue, unwind-segue

I have two view controllers VC1 and VC2. I pass a value from VC1 to VC2 through `prepareForSegue` method. and when I receive that value in VC2 I multiply it by 10.

what I want to do is, after multiplying that value by 10 in VC2 I want to return it back to VC1.

such scenario could be done using `Intents` and `BroadcastReceiver`. how can I do that in iOS using objective.c?

Comment: Use delegates Google about it issue solved.

Comment: There are a few options to share data with other objects: delegation, notification, properties, singletons..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: @Marcio Romero Patrnogic OP question says he wants one to one process for passing values . Which is best solved by delegates.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure about .. "best solved by gelegates".. there are many scenarios when other solutions could be better.. What I am trying to say is that there are a few options out there that he should evaluate before making a decision

Comment: Go for Delegates. See this for more info: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-to-pass-values-between-multiple-view-controllers-using-delegate-protocol

Comment: Lets say he has an object "Person", he passes the reference from VC1 to VC2. Then he sets Person.Name = "RandomName". He doesnt need to write any code, because he has updated the same person. VC1 has the reference to that person and he will see the change without extra code.

Comment: @Marcio Romero Patrnogic it's a general thumb rule delegates - one to one , Notification -: one to many , KVO - much more you have here.

Comment: Then what if its an object and he passes the reference.. its way easier than delegation? my point is it depends on what he needs

Comment: @MarcioRomeroPatrnogic so, I think you recommend KVO over delegates, don't you?

Comment: I am not suggesting KVO.. Its just simple OOP

Comment: @TusharSharma I used the delegate as you suggested, but would you please check this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45513017/how-to-call-the-required-method-in-a-delegate-in-the-implementation-file.     I have a problem in calling the method of the delegate

Comment: I am not objective -c guy but this might help-: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c

Comment: @SivajeeBattina I used delegate as you suggested but I have a problem calling the method of the delegate, would you please have a look at this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45513017/how-to-call-the-required-method-in-a-delegate-in-the-implementation-file

Comment: @user2121 Avoid poisting multiple questions with the same issue. You have made an issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45513017/how-to-call-the-required-method-in-a-delegate-in-the-implementation-file . You can instead update your question with the suggestions and get an answer in the same thread.