# how to call the required method in a delegate in the implementation file

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have two view controllers VC1 and VC2. I pass a value from VC1 to VC2 through prepareForSegue method. and when I receive that value in VC2 I multiply it by 10. Then after multiplying that value by 10 in VC2 I want to return it back to VC1.

to solve this issue, I would use `Delegate`. so, I created `DelegateDataProcessor` class

but I do not know how to call the required method `processingDone` in the method `startProcessingValue`

please have a look at the code below

** DelegateDataProcessor.h**:

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 @protocol ProtocolDataProcessor <NSObject>

 @required
 - (void) processingDone;
 @end


 @interface DelegateDataProcessor : NSObject{

 id <ProtocolDataProcessor> _delegate;
 }

 @property (nonatomic, strong) id delegate;

-(void) startProcessingValue: (NSInteger) valueToBeProcessed;

@end
```

** DelegateDataProcessor.m**:

```
#import "DelegateDataProcessor.h"

@implementation DelegateDataProcessor

-(void) startProcessing:(NSInteger) value {

 value = value * 10;

//How to call the method `processingDone` here

}
@end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create delegates in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c)

Comment: @user2121 - you would benefit greatly by reading through that linked post, as well as a few other articles / tutorials / documentation pages so that you **understand** how Delegate Protocols work... however, if you just want a quick answer without any context: `[_delegate processingDone];`

Comment: I think you are a bit confused on how to achieve delegation.. I came here from your prev question.. feel free to pm me fb.com/mrpatrnogic i can explain you how to properly implement this later if you want

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your data from VC2 to VC1 via a protocol:

- Add a method to protocol:

  ```
  -(void)getValue:(NSInteger)myInteger;
  ```
- On method prepare for segue, define VC1 as VC2's delegate
- When you want come back from VC2 to VC1 call method getValue by passing your value.

I wish that I explained clearly.